# Necessary condition for $a_m=\sum_{p=0}^{m}\binom{m}{p}a_p\binom{m}{p}\cos^{2p}(\theta) \sin^{2m-2p}(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, combinations

Given a list of complex number $a_0,\ldots,a_m$ satisfying $$a_m=\sum_{p=0}^{m}\binom{m}{p}a_p\binom{m}{p}\cos^{2p}(\theta) \sin^{2m-2p}(\theta)$$ for arbitrary $\theta\in\mathbb R$, then is it necessary $\binom{m}{p}a_p=a_m$? Well, it’s clear it’s sufficient, but for my purpose, I actually require it to be necessary, but I haven’t see how it is necessary. Any advices?

Comment: Is $C_m^p = \binom{p}{m}$?

Comment: I just realized the notation is wrong... Let me change it into your fashion. @Gary